# 1. Adding printer share to file server 2. AD Account lock after changing password. WHY?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer, active-directory

I have a mindbender that I am looking for help to solve.

After changing my AD password my account keeps getting lock.

I found the workstation that was sending the wrong password and locking me.

The way I fixed the problem is by removing a shared printer I had just added 1 week ago.

What I want to know is what am i doing wrong when adding the new printer to the fileserver that locks my account? My fileserver is a Windows Server 2008 R2.

EDIT.

Just to clarify a few things. Here is the step of how i get locked.

1. add shared printer to fileserver
2. add user who i want to be able to use the printer under object security.
3. the user connect to the printer by browsing to the fileserver address and clicking on the printer(At no point i enter my credential on that computer)
4. user use the printer, everything is fine.
5. I change my password, Then i start getting lock.
6. I find out which computer is locking me, the user who connected to the printer i shared.
7. I Go to that computer and remove the shared printer.
8. I stop getting locked.

What do i need to do to be able to share a printer on the file server without being locked?

Answer (score 1):

Cached credentials will cause Windows to try and contact the print server with your old password, which of course fails and eventually locks out your account.

To fix, simply log off and back on the affected machine with your new password. You can even lock/unlock the screen to get a similar effect.

Comment: Cached credential where?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.windowsconfidential.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In a domain environment, you don't need to save credentials, but somehow, sometimes, Windows will do if for you anyway. You can remove the cached credentials by navigating:
Control Panel/User Accounts/Manger your Credentials
And then clicking "remove from vault"

[image: vault]

Comment: Yep. Windows will store passwords automatically for servers you authenticate to (the "remember my credentials" box). This includes file shares, printer shares, and RDP session credentials. Basically anywhere you see a Windows security prompt (yes, websites too!) it can be stored there.